# Replicating records in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of rows in Excel which contain data for a particular month. The month is identified by a column called 'Month' and the data in this column is in the format `mm/yyyy`.

Now, I would like to duplicate these records vertically for each of the next 11 months, and each time it is duplicated, the month rows should change for that month (e.g. the second time it is duplicated, the month rows should show February and then the next time March, etc.).

What's the best way to do this apart from copy and pasting 11 times and manually changing the months?

Comment: i would copy 11 times, instead of writing macro... 11 is not that bad to repeat (if this was like 300 id consider something else) to deal with month issue, i'd separate month and year first, either manually or by =year() and =month() function first. say for the sake of argument you have 36 records. so your original data ends in row 37 (assuming first row is header). then in row38, in put formula like =a2+1, so that i get the following month. copy this for the down down down, in this way you got 36 lines of same number, incremented by one and then another 36 rows and so on. you copy this thing

Comment: There are a couple of non-manual copying/pasting solutions. (1) Code which 23 can write if you have a preference (2) Using OFFSET formula on a separate sheet with some manipulation to add months to your date column. Do you have a preference?

Answer (score 1):

The OFFSET approach needs only two formulas copied over to a new sheet to set up the extended data set

This sample assumes

- your current sheet is called sheet1
- your month data mm/yyyy starts in row 2, and is in column A

Changing the sheet name and column in the two formulas below is easy, if your data to extract started on row 3 not row 2 then change all `ROW()-2)` to `ROW()-3)` etc

While the first looks messier than it really is (to add 1 month), the concept is straightforward. The OFFSET approach moves down one cell from Sheet 1 only every 12 rows, the month being tweaked each cell

1. In A2 put, `=DATE(YEAR(OFFSET(Sheet1!A$2,INT((ROW()-2)/12),0)),MONTH(OFFSET(Sheet1!A$2,INT((ROW()-2)/12),0))+MOD(ROW()-2,12),DAY(OFFSET(Sheet1!A$2,INT((ROW()-2)/12),0)))`
2. In B2 put, `=OFFSET(Sheet1!B$2,INT((ROW()-2)/12),0)` and copy over as far as you have fields

[image]

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood OP's question.  Yours seems more likely tasks that needs to be done....

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly enough, Excel 2007 *(only one I have available)* understands mm/yyyy as a date, so the formula `=TEXT(DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+1,1),"mm/yyyy")` creates the next date, and can be copied down.
Duplicating other data would simply be a case of putting the values as `=B2` and so forth